# ListVectorPlot3D: not a valid vector field dataset

Tags: plotting

I have tried to do a `ListVectorPlot3D`, but I obtain the following error

```
 ListVectorPlot3D[data]

 Visualization`Core`ListVectorPlot3D::vfldata: 

{{-457.,-539.,1.,0.,0.,0.},{-455.,-539.,1.,0.,0.,0.},{-453.,-539.,1.,0.,0.,0.},{-451.,-539.,1.,0.,0.,0.},{-449.,-539.,1.,0.,0.,0.},{-447.,-539.,1.,0.,0.,0.},{-445.,-539.,1.,0.,0.,0.},{-443.,-539.,1.,0.,0.,0.},<<183966>>} is not a valid vector field dataset or a valid list of datasets. obtain the following error:
```

The dimensions of the data is  $\{184016, 6\}$. For construct the data, I use:

```
 data = Table[{Plane[[i, 1]], Plane[[i, 2]], Plane[[i, 3]],  Plane[[i, 4]], Plane[[i, 5]], Plane[[i, 6]]}, {i, 1, Length[Plane], 1}];
```

where "plane" corresponds to the imported data.

thanks

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that reproduces the problem?

Comment: `ListVectorPlot3D` needs `{{posx,posy, posz}, {vx, vy, vz}}`. You have flattened the list. You need to do `ListVectorPlot3D[Partition[#,3]& /@ Plane]`

Comment: What is the definition of "Plane" in the above example?  I think @flinty has the right solution.

Comment: ListVectorPlot3D[Partition[#,3]& /@ Plane] does not work, I have the same error  Visualization`Core`ListVectorPlot3D::vfldata: {{{-457.,-539.,1.},{0.,0.,0.}},{{-455.,-539.,1.},{0.,0.,0.}},{{-453.,-539.,1.},{0.,0.,0.}},{{-451.,-539.,1.},{0.,0.,0.}},{{-449.,-539.,1.},{0.,0.,0.}},{{-447.,-539.,1.},{0.,0.,0.}},...183966>>} is not a valid vector field dataset or a valid list of datasets.